# unaccessible IP address using IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, server-side

Recenly a network card was intalled on the server so that I can have a new IP address for my application.

Whend deploying the application on the server using IIS (using the "add site" feature) and then test the site , the site works perfectly fine from withtin the server

but when I try to access it from outside the server I get the message saying that the site is not reachable

any reason why this is happening ?

Comment: It sounds more like a firewall related issue. Check to make sure you can remotely access that ip address... one way is to do a ping test. RUN--> CMD--> ping 192.168.1.100 (insert your ip here) -t

Comment: I did ping the IP address and it is not reachable :( but even the other IP addresses on the server are not "pingable" either but they are reachable if I type them in a browser

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a firewall issue.  First make sure the windows firewall isn't blocking IIS.  Also make sure your IT team has setup that IP address as an external server.

A few other questions about your server

1) What type of services are you hosting and is it on the standard ports? ([Exhaustive list of ports on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers))

2) What version of IIS are you using?

3) Do you have a firewall/load balancer/etc between your server and the web?

Comment: so in answer to your questions
1-I am hosting an HTTP application (port 80) but I am aiming to switch it to port 443 (HTTPS) in the future
2-I am using IIS7
3-how can I check about that ? I think that there is no firewall but I need to check

Comment: @user1415780, who is doing your IT security... they should be able to help with this.